# Using postman raw testing spring-boot controller failed

Tags: spring-boot, postman

Here is the controller:

[image: controller]

Here is the postman:

Via form-data, I can get `caseId` in my controller.

[image: form-data]

But raw with header, I can't.

[image: raw]

[image: header]

I don't know why... Is there anything wrong with my controller ?

Please help, thanks.

---

edit 1:

Yeah. Add something more

We know, springMVC will bind data for us, but when we use POST request and put data in body via `raw and Content-Type:application/json`, spring will still bind data? `request.getInputStream()` will only call once.

---

edit 2:

I found a way to get the raw.

[image: the way]

get the json string.

[image: get this]

---

edit in 11/29/2017

I found that:

Post with raw, I need to use `@RequestBody` to recive the value.

Comment: Any error you getting ?

Comment: Nothing error but get `null` value.

Comment: Where you call `/getTCase`?

Comment: local environment, `https://localhost:7443/zk/getTCase`

Comment: How you pass the `String caseId` ? It looked like you are passing a null value to `getTCaseByCaseId` method.

Comment: Er... Put it into the body of POST request?

Comment: Wait...you mean you want to get the `caseId` from postman ?

Comment: Yeah ... It should be bind by springMVC ...

Comment: Why not post to POSTMAN using Spring boot ?

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the example of how to retrieve data using `POSTMAN` and bind with `SpringMVC`

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            // You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

You may refer to this article : [Spring Boot Rest API Example](http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-api-example/)

Comment: OK, I know these things, but weither we do the same thing when the data  from body `form-data` or `raw with Content-Type:application/json` ?

Comment: I don't get you meant

Comment: Is that spring won't bind data that in POST body raw?

Answer (score 0):

Can u bind request param as below and check :

```
 public Object getTcaseByCaseId(@RequestParam("caseId") String caseId) {
```